# match the dataframe columns with list values and append dataframe with matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two different csv's which I read in two dataframes. I want to match the columns df1['building_type] with df2['model'] and append the corresponding row to the df1.

Dataframe 1:

```
data = [{'length': '34', 'width': '58.5', 'height': '60.2', 'building_type': ['concrete','wood','steel','laminate']},
       {'length': '42', 'width': '33', 'height': '23', 'building_type': ['concrete_double','wood_double','steel_double']}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df1)
```

Dataframe 2:

```
data2 = [{'type': 'A1', 'floor': '2', 'model': ['wood','laminate','concrete','steel']},
       {'type': 'B3', 'floor': '4',  'model': ['wood_double','concrete_double','steel_double']}]
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)
```

Final dataframe:

```
   length   width   height  building_type                                 type  floor
0   34      58.5    60.2   [concrete, wood, steel, laminate]              A1    2
1   42      33      23     [concrete_double, wood_double, steel_double]   B3    4
```

Comment: in your question, all the elements of both lists match, but would you match if it is a partial match, like only 3 over 4 elements for example?

Comment: no all elements should match. the length of the list would be the same as well while matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.merge` seems to be the necessary tool here but we'll need an immutable dtype. `list` is mutable and cannot be joined on. We can convert `list` (mutable) to `tuple` or `frozenset`, both of which are immutable and can be used to join on. Since the sample output shows that order doesn't matter, I went with `frozenset`.

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'length': '34', 'width': '58.5', 'height': '60.2', 'building_type': ['concrete','wood','steel','laminate']},
       {'length': '42', 'width': '33', 'height': '23', 'building_type': ['concrete_double','wood_double','steel_double']}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)

data2 = [{'type': 'A1', 'floor': '2', 'model': ['wood','laminate','concrete','steel']},
       {'type': 'B3', 'floor': '4',  'model': ['wood_double','concrete_double','steel_double']}]
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)


# Note: Merge fails on mutable dtype
# pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='building_type', right_on='model')
# Produces `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

# Convert mutable type to immutable type and merge.
# `tuple` is best if order matters for you. I am assuming that the
# order doesn't matter based on the sample output, so `frozenset` is more
# appropriate.
df1['building_type'] = df1['building_type'].apply(frozenset)
df2['model'] = df2['model'].apply(frozenset)

# Now, merge. Note that since column names are different both
# 'building_type' and 'model' would be retained. You can remove one of them.
final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='building_type', right_on='model')
final_df = final_df.drop(['model'], axis=1)
print(final_df)
```

Output on my machine:

```
  length width height                                 building_type
0     34  58.5   60.2             [concrete, wood, steel, laminate]
1     42    33     23  [concrete_double, wood_double, steel_double]
  type floor                                         model
0   A1     2             [wood, laminate, concrete, steel]
1   B3     4  [wood_double, concrete_double, steel_double]
  length width height                                 building_type type floor
0     34  58.5   60.2             (laminate, wood, steel, concrete)   A1     2
1     42    33     23  (concrete_double, steel_double, wood_double)   B3     4
```